# Unknown property 'contacts' referenced in AccountVF, call Apex from VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to get the first 10 Contact and display them in a `VisualForce Page`.

I developed the below code, but it gives me this error:

> Unknown property 'contacts' referenced in AccountVF

**ContactController**

```
public class ContactController {
    public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}

    public List<Contact> getContacts(){
        contacts = [select Id, FirstName, LastName From Contact LIMIT 10];
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

**AccountVF**

```
<apex:page action="ContactController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c">
                <apex:column value="{!c.FirstName}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.LastName}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the controller using the `controller` attribute in your `<apex:page>` tag, not its `action` attribute:

```
<apex:page controller="ContactController">
```

As mentioned by others, your syntax introduces some conflict, since your `Visualforce` has two different ways to "get" the `contacts` variable. I would suggest you go with the lazy loading pattern here since you consume a query in the getter:

```
public List<Contact> contacts
{
    get
    {
        if (contacts == null)
            contacts = [/*query*/];
        return contacts;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Comment: Guess I've got slow fingers today.

Comment: You really should mention that using a public variable and get/set methods by the same name can lead to unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the suggestions. I would need to use `constructor` instead of the any method, then only I can see the data.

```
public class ContactController {
    public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}

    public ContactController(){
        contacts = [select Id, FirstName, LastName From Contact LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

Comment: It was your `Visualforce` that needed correction. Regardless, setting it in the constructor is a good way to go. I suggest you go with `private set` unless you actually want something else setting this variable.

Comment: Ok, I understood your suggestion. But what correction is needed in VF page? Can you tell me that ?

Comment: It's in my answer. You specified `ContactController` as the `action` attribute rather than the `controller` attribute.